# Emulate NFC Forum mandated tags 1 or 2

Tags: android, usb, nfc

Do you see any possibility to emulate NFC Forum tag 1 or 2 on mobile device not using the secure element – this I consider impossible? More realistic sounds the scenario of emulating them on desktop using the NFC Reader…

Any suggestions?
Regards,
STeN

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any possibility. Technically it is not impossible, but to my knowledge there are is no NFC chip for mobile devices available that has this as a feature. Using a desktop NFC reader, I think this is possible in some cases: [libnfc supports it](http://www.libnfc.org/documentation/examples/nfc-emulate).

Comment: Seems that the libnfc is pretty popular... Totally agree that there is not any know possibility on decive currently, but with USB reader I will give it a try...

Comment: Hi @STeN did you ever develop tag emulation using a desktop device.